# Java MQ consumer - How to control message consumuption rate

Tags: java, microservices, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using Spring JMS (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) to read messages from an IBM MQ, call an endpoint, and on success acknowledge the message (Client Ack). I need to control the rate at which the microservice calls the endpoint.

Is there any way to control the rate at which the consumer consume message? Say the microservice to consume 1 message per second (maximum).

I tried to configure the concurrency to 1 and poll interval (1000 milliseconds) but this does not control the rate at which messages are consumed. That is if the entire process completes in 500 milliseconds then the service immediately picks up another message without waiting.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63921553/638413)?

Comment: @DanielSteinmann I had a look at it but that was limited to one concurrency. Is there a way to have multiple concurrency and control the rate at which each consumer picks up a message?
I was wondering whether this was provided out-of-the-box by the JMSTemplate (DefaultMessageListener) or by the IBM MQ library

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario you can try using receive method that JmsTemplate provides.

```
i.e. jmsTemplate.receive(destination);
```

This lets you consume messages on demand.
You can wrap this logic inside a scheduler which runs for every 1 second

Comment: Thanks @dhanraj. I tried this and it works. I was wondering whether this is provided by the DefaultMessageListenerContainer or is there a method that I can override it. One of the reasons why I want to go with MQ is to control the rate at which I send messages to my legacy system.